# Creating delete query in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm kind of new using laravel. 
I created delete function but it doesnt work as I wanted to. Here are the codes in view, controller as well as routes. Could you guys tell me what was wrong in the code? Thanks

View:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{  URL::to('/delete_data_tanah/{id}') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-close" 
        onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this data?');">----</i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function delete($id){
    \App\Tbl_object::where('id_objects', '=', $id)->delete();
    return redirect('/list_tanah')->with('Success', 'Data telah dihapus');
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/delete_data_tanah/{id}', 'formulir_tanah@delete');
```

Controller:

```
class formulir_tanah extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $query_tanah = \App\Tbl_object::where('id_objects_referencies', '=', '1')->get();
        $query_view = \App\Tbl_view::where('id_objects_referencies', '=', '1')->get();
        $data = ['page_title' => 'Kertas Kerja Penilaian Tanah', 'query_tanah' => $query_tanah, 'query_view' => $query_view];
        return view('admin/list_tanah')->with($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: is there any error when you execute your code?

Comment: Could you please add the code of the controller for your view?

Comment: @FrankerZ I can click on the button, but nothing happened and there's no error. Just nothing happened.

Comment: @Capt.Teemo no error and nothing happened.

Comment: @SvenHakvoort which view?

Comment: @RizkaHutami, the code/controller with which you call your template (html)

Comment: @SvenHakvoort this one:                                                                          
 class formulir_tanah extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
  //ambil semua data dari table categories
     $query_tanah = \App\Tbl_object::where('id_objects_referencies', '=', '1')->get();
     $query_view = \App\Tbl_view::where('id_objects_referencies', '=', '1')->get();

     $data = [
      'page_title' => 'Kertas Kerja Penilaian Tanah',
      'query_tanah' => $query_tanah,
      'query_view' => $query_view
     ];
     return view('admin/list_tanah')->with($data);
 }

Comment: And the contents of Tbl_object?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort tbl_object is the table which contains the data that will be deleted.

Comment: @RizkaHutami, I understand that ;) I just need the code so I can provide a correct and complete answer with the right variable names :)

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I'm really sorry :) I was kind of confused what information on the Tbl_object that you need (since it contains a lot of variable names). Should I just write all the variable names on the Tbl_object?

Comment: @rizkahut no problem :) the main thing I would like to know is how the ID is defined which you want to use to delete it

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I see. The ID is defined as id_objects , there's also id_objects_referencies to differentiate the type of objects. In this case, the only data that shown on the table and I want to delete always have id_objects_referencies : 1.

Comment: @rizkahut maybe because laravel doesn't what row to delete. have you tried setting a static `id` in your `href`? like `href="{{  URL::to('/delete_data_tanah/1') }}"`

Comment: @Capt.Teemo yes, I did and it works. So how could I change this into id_objects? I tried several codes to state the id_objects, but still doesnt work..

Comment: @rizkahut can you show the code on how you retrieve the data that you want to delete?

Comment: @Capt.Teemo here is the controller:  `class formulir_tanah extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
  //ambil semua data dari table categories
        
     $query_tanah = \App\Tbl_object::where('id_objects_referencies', '=', '1')
         ->get();
     $query_view = \App\Tbl_view::where('id_objects_referencies', '=', '1')
         ->get();
        

     $data = [
      'page_title' => 'Kertas Kerja Penilaian Tanah',
      'query_tanah' => $query_tanah,
      'query_view' => $query_view
     ];
     return view('admin/list_tanah')->with($data);
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

in your blade.php, change `{id}` to `{$data->id}`

```
<div class="btn-group">
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{  URL::to('/delete_data_tanah/{$data->id}') }}">
    <i class="fa fa-close" 
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this data?');">----</i>
</a>
```

then in your controller, add the `id` variable:

```
class formulir_tanah extends Controller { public function index(){ 
    //ambil semua data dari table categories
     $query_tanah = \App\Tbl_object::where('id_objects_referencies', '=', '1')->first(); 
     $query_view = \App\Tbl_view::where('id_objects_referencies', '=', '1') ->first(); 

     $data = ['id' => $query_view->id, 'page_title' => 'Kertas Kerja Penilaian Tanah', 'query_tanah' => $query_tanah, 'query_view' => $query_view ];

     return view('admin/list_tanah')->with($data);
}
```

your code doesn't work since laravel doesn't know what row to delete since there is no specific `id` in your return.

Comment: I tried, but I got this error:     'Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.'

Comment: I edited my answer. Try changing `get()` to `first()`

Comment: I tried, but then it doesn work and now I cant retrieve the data in view, but the data is there.. but didnt show up in the view

Answer (score 0):

Apply these changes to your code:

```
Route::delete('/delete_data_tanah/{id}', 'formulir_tanah@delete');
```

and in your view you need to wrap the button in a form

```
<form action="{{  URL::to('/delete_data_tanah/{id}') }}" method="post">
   @method('DELETE')
   @csrf
  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got this error:   protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
    {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
    }

Comment: Does your `delete` function exists in the controller as well? 
Where does that `$others` comes from?

Comment: yes, delete function exists in the controller as well.. was it the problem?